# VisualSVN Support Questions

Tags: visualsvn, visualsvn-server

We are one step from acquiring the VirtualSVN server license (to get the Windows authentication feature), but our IT responsible is somewhat reluctant because the support from VisualSVN (the "company") is somewhere between very slow and not responding.

Looking at their website you can't tell whether it is actually a running company with full time employees or "just" some brilliant programmers with too much spare time. Please tell me about your experience with the support from VisualSVN. Where are they located? How many are they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual SVN is just a GUI frontend for Apache+SVN+Windows Auth

It is fine for a single developer machine and testing purpose.
But if you ask me, for production use I would install apache and ldap auth and svn directly (shouldn't be too hard at all).

http://svn.spears.at/
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/SubversionApache.aspx
http://geekswithblogs.net/flanakin/archive/2005/08/31/51743.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: my name is Danil Shopyrin and I'm managing director at VisualSVN.

I'm really sorry for the fact that some support requests are handled too slow.

For your information, VisualSVN is an independent software vendor and we have full time employees since 2006. The problem is that during last years our market share have dramatically exceeded the size of our company.

We are working hard to expand our office. I hope the problem will be finally solved in the next few months. We are a customer-oriented company and great technical support is the key factor of our success.

And of course, we have some brilliant programmers here at VisualSVN.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Danil. Maybe you can answer my two questions: Where are you located? How many full-time employees are there in the company?